# How to make javascript contact form submit correctly

Tags: javascript, php, email

html code:
    
        
            Contact Me

```
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="Name" accesskey="N" tabindex="1">

                <label for="Email">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="Email" accesskey="E" tabindex="1">

                <label for="Phone">Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="number" id="Number" tabindex="1">

                <label for="Comment">Comments</label>
                <textarea type="text" name="comment" id="Comment" rows="27" cols="70" tabindex="1"></textarea>

                <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

email.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

  if (!$email)
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please enter a valid email address...');history.back();</script>";

  else {
    $to = "randomemail@gmail.com"; //change this to YOUR email address

    $name = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : "anonymous";
    $number = (isset($_POST['number'])) ? $_POST['number'] : "none";
    $comment = (isset($_POST['comment'])) ? $_POST['comment'] : "none";

    $subject = "Message from $name via contact form";

    $message = "Name: $name\nNumber: $number\nEmail: $email\nMessage: $comment";

    $from = "From: " . $name . "<" . $email .">\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: " . $email ."\r\n" .
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $from))
      header("Location: thanks.html");

    else
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('An unknown system error has occurred!');history.back();</script>";
  }
}

?>
```

when you submit, it loads email.php, but only a white page, not the thanks.html that it should.

Comment: Please `echo` a response for every possible outcome of an `if` statement, and post the response you get to find exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to name your submit field:

```
            <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Don't use form fields to detect a post. Use the 100% reliable:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... }
```

instead. This will ALWAYS be true if a POST was performed. As you can see with your version, a simple typo or oversight will completely kill your logic.

Answer (score 0):

First Empty your file and just put `header("Location: thanks.html");` in your php tags. If it works then add the other lines progressively. you'll see the annoying line. Read about header on PHP reference website. It should be used carefully